PyAudio - microphone has no channels
I am trying to capture audio input from my Windows microphone using PyAudio. To open the stream, I want to set the input_device_index and for that, I have written the following code:
def scan_audio_devices(audio):
    dev_index = -1
    foundIt = False
    for ii in range(audio.get_device_count()):
        print("device at " + str(ii) + " - " + str(audio.get_device_info_by_index(ii).get('name')))
        if str(audio.get_device_info_by_index(ii).get('name')).startswith("Microphone") and audio.get_device_info_by_index(ii).get('channels') is not None:
            dev_index = ii
            print('FOUND MICROPHONE AT INDEX: '+str(ii))
            foundIt=True
            break
    if not foundIt:
        for ii in range(audio.get_device_count()):
            if audio.get_device_info_by_index(ii).get('channels') is not None:
                dev_index = ii
                print('FOUND MICROPHONE AT INDEX: '+str(ii))
                break
    return dev_index

However, the dev_index return value is always -1. When I try to force it to the correct microphone device index, number of channels is None and it says

OSError: [Errno -9998] Invalid number of channels

(note, this also happens when I forgot setting input_device_index and instead trust it to use system default).
Is there a setting that I must make on the input device to state the number of channels before opening the stream?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75037622/pyaudio-oserror-errno-9998-invalid-number-of-channels-on-mac-with-external

That worked. Thanks.
